# flex - how to set the background color of a spark check box text label?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a simple spark mxml check box and I want to change the background color via actionscript.    I have searched and tried many suggestions, including using setStyle with 'background-color', 'chromeColor', symbolColor and others like this - the only thing that worked at all is chromeColor, which colored the box but not the text or background:

```
insUpdatedCB.setStyle('chromeColor','yellow');
```

I also tried using text format like this:

```
var myTf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTf.size = 16; 
myTf.color = 0xFF0000; 
insUpdatedCB.setStyle("textFormat", myTf);
```

also did not work

how can I set the label/text background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the background color of the spark checkbox, then you have to apply a custom skin for it. Make a new Custom skin by making a copy of default checkboxSkin for spark checkbox, and then change the background color of the label in the Custom Skin.

Comment: So it looks like this might be what you are talking about: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/04/14/setting-a-custom-skin-class-on-a-spark-checkbox-control-in-flex-4/